# Change/Rename Controller Name In URL: Yii2

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii-url-manager

I was looking to change controller name in URL. Which, we can do by renaming the controller name in module. But, Through URL manager if we can do it. It will be better.

**Module**: user,
**Controller**: api,
**Action**: index

Right now,

```
'urlManager' => [
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'showScriptName' => false,
  'rules' => [
        '<controller:(api)>/<action:\w+>/<id:[a-z0-9]+>' => 'user/<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:(api)>/<action>' => 'user/<controller>/<action>',
    ]
];
```

And, I can access it through.

```
http://dev.example.com/api/index
```

But, I was looking to change it to

```
http://dev.example.com/world/index
```

How can I do it? Any help/hint/suggestion is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom url rules by adding items to the rules array.

So, in your case insert this into the rules array

```
'world/index' => 'api/index'
```

You can read more about URL rules [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

also you use ControllerMap

it useful when you are using third-party controllers and you do not have control over their class names.

below code in component in main.php in advance or web.php in basic
for example:

```
    'controllerMap' => [           
        'api' => 'app\controllers\WorldController',
                        ]
```